# Failed to load resource: in Laravel 5.5.4

Tags: laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5.4. I installed a package GitHub repository. Now while I am trying browse the project `http://127.0.0.1/myproject/public/register` I am getting error `Failed to load resource:`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup your web server properly to look into public directory. Check the installation manual.

Comment: Thanks @arku. I couldn't find anything like you said.

Comment: Check here for example - https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-16-04/
The core is you have to setup your web server to show 'localhost/laravel/public' directory instead of  'localhost'

Comment: Thanks @arku for your reply. I tried to follow your instruction but it is also not working. Thanks

Comment: so, you have a web-server configured to a public directory and when you open your page in a browser it still not working? I bet nope, You didn't follow instructions and didn't setup your web server properly. As a fast fix I could also suggest run php artisan server and get result by url http://localhost:8000/